# UICollectionView resizes cells incorrectly after reloadData

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that renders some autosizing cells. When I load the data into the collection view initially, the data is perfectly sized the way it should be.

I have a weird issue where, when I trigger `reloadData` with a new data set, the auto sizing goes wrong and I end up with incorrectly sized cells.

Images attached.

I have tried invalidating the `collectionViewLayout` before I call `reloadData`.

Oddly enough, if I remove data, and trigger a `reloadData` the cells resize to their correct layout. So I am wondering if this is a view recycling issue?

Thanks in advance.

Below is the layout after the screen was initially loaded for the first time.

[image: First load of data]

Below is the layout after the `+` opens a modal to add a new post, closes, and refreshes the data - see incorrect sizing of cell "Thanks for all your hard work".

[image: reloadData]

Below is the screen after the screen was reloaded from scratch again.

[image: delete reloadData]

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be a bit late, but getting the similar behaviour I did manage to solve it. 
In my case, the problem was with multiline labels — so changing them to single-line solved the case.
As I didn't need to have multilines — I had no further research on them.

I hope, this answer could be a good starting point to find a fix.